# When to use alloc

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ive tried digging around in old posts, but they were kind of obsolete and years old, so I was concerned things might have changed due to ARC being introduced etc.

Mainly I was looking at some fairly new code that used alloc on an array, which was declared as a property in the header. I was thinking, I don't normally do this and everything is working smoothly. But then came to my mind UIButton and UILabel for example, which has to have alloc invoked, or they won't be added to the view when you want that. Are there any rough guidelines for when its actually needed. I would think any object needs this, but the array vs. button/label thing as I just described made me wonder what is the reasoning behind this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use alloc always if you create the object on your own.
Which means that sending alloc is normally followed by an init method.

It might sometimes look like it's not always the case, as many classes have convenient constructors that return an already allocated and initialized object to you.
But there is still alloc and init called to create the object.
It's just done for you by the system.
But the difference between convenient constructors and manually creating objects isn't new to ARC, it has always been around.

Example for creating an NSArray on your own:

```
[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Test", nil];
```

and as NSArray has an convenient constructor here the example for that:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test", nil];
```

If you use ARC, there is no real difference.
Without ARC, the object returned by the convenient constructor would still be autoreleased, while the manually allocated object has to be released by you at a later point (or you have to add an autorelease after the init).

So the main difference is the owner ship:
In the manually created example the object belongs to you, so you are responsible to clean up after you don't need it anymore.

Comment: will it be autoreleased without arc, because autorelease is invoked within arrayWithObjects method?

Comment: Yes, arrayWithObjects returns you an autoreleased object.

Comment: sry, u wrote that in your reply, don't know what i was thinking:) The book I am reading atm, have not released any objects that have been alloc'ed, like your first example or when you do [NSString alloc]initWithString:@"XXX"]; does NSArray's initWithObjects also invoke autorelease in its implementation?

Comment: No, without ARC there's no autorelease sent.
But when using ARC, you don't have to manually add retains/releases or autorelease. The system handles that for you and will release objects out of scope.
So most likely you book is already based on ARC.

Comment: yea ok, the reply below and its comments got me confused

Answer (score 2):

This is 100% dependent on the actual objects being used from the framework.  The really great news, though, is that Apple is extremely consistent.  If you send a message that contains an "Alloc" in it anywhere, you are responsible for making sure that it has been released.

[Here's a super document on it from Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Comment: I thought this was a thing of the past, after ARC was introduced I have not relied on releasing anymore. Anyway, I don't think this answers why buttons and labels need to be alloc'ed, as opposed to an NSArray which you can work with trouble free without doing it. Ill mark your answer if nothing more descriptive comes along soon. Thx again, and a good link posted, ty.

Comment: It is not a thing of the past and it does explain the buttons.  Check the document. :)  It's all about how the API for the particular object works.  If you call something that has "alloc" in its name then you are responsible for it.  There are a few others too, but I've been in Swift land for a while and I forget offhand.

Answer (score 1):

If something is declared in .xib then it is automatically allocated for you. Just use it. While If you are creating a view in code u must alloc it first. And if you have a property NSArray/NSMutableArray etc, u might be doing one of the following:

```
_array = [NSArray new];
_array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
_array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: values count:2];
_array = @ ["ABC", "xyz"];
```

etc,
so you are actually allocating it if you are using any of these methods.

Comment: Every method that returns an object reference can be an allocator. Look at `-componentsJoinedByString:` (`NSArray`) for example.

Comment: Yes. Basically, My point was allocation is required this way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand, what

> they won't be added to the view when you want that.

means, but here is the story:

*Every* object is allocated using `+alloc`. To be honest, it is `+allocWithZone:`, but this does not have any meaning at this place.

The very first message you have to send to the newly created instance object (remember: you sent `+alloc` to the class object) is an initialization message, something like `init…`. To put this together you will find code as:

```
… [[TheClass alloc] init…] …;
```

Because it is boring typing there are `new` allocators. They put this messages into one:

```
… [TheClass new…] …;
```

(This has some advantages for the class implementor, too, but this is transparent to you. Think of it as sending `+alloc`, `-init…`.)

In earlier times it has been a good idea to send an autorelease message to it as the next step for some reasons:

```
… [[[TheClass alloc] init…] autorelease] …;
```

This has been put together to convenience allocators:

```
… [TheClass theClass…] …
```

This is what you find most of the time when reading old code. Using ARC you do not need convenience allocators anymore: There is no autorelease. So there is no reason for convenience allocators anymore. But we had MRR for years and there are still many convenience allocators. (Now called factory methods, but CA's are only a subset of these. A subset you do not have to care about. It's all gone with ARC.) Because there are that many CA's, one still uses them. (And there is a performance issue with them. In nowadays I only write `new` allocators, which has the advantages of a CA, but not the disadvantage of autorelease.)

To make a long story short: You simply do not see sometimes that `+alloc` is used.